# Pass an optional property from main oozie workflow to subworkflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have an HDFS_file_path or property that needs to be passed from workflow-1 to common_subworkflow.

I also have workflow-2 which doesn't have that property or HDFS_file_path. But workflow-2 calls common_subworkflow.

In common_subworkflow I am fetching the property value with ${HDFS_file_path}.

It works fine when workflow-1 calls common_subworkflow but fails when workflow-2 calls common_subworkflow since HDFS_file_path doesn't exist in workflow-2.

Is there any way to

1. read the dynamic property if present, or

   2. set some default value(null or empty) if variable not present

Comment: share you workflow and sub workflow

Answer (score 3):

```
<workflow-app name='hello-wf' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <parameters>
        <property>
            <name>inputDir</name>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>outputDir</name>
            <value>out-dir</value>
        </property>
    </parameters>
    ...
    <action name='firstjob'>
        <map-reduce>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.mapper.class</name>
                    <value>com.foo.FirstMapper</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.reducer.class</name>
                    <value>com.foo.FirstReducer</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.input.dir</name>
                    <value>${inputDir}</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.output.dir</name>
                    <value>${outputDir}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </map-reduce>
        <ok to='secondjob'/>
        <error to='killcleanup'/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

In the above example, if inputDir is not specified, Oozie will print an error message instead of submitting the job. If =outputDir= is not specified, Oozie will use the default value, out-dir .

Taken from https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.1_Workflow_Job_Properties_or_Parameters